# Paste together each pair of columns in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame of amino acid sites, and want to create a new data frame of each pairwise combination of these sites.

The original data will look something like this:

```
df<-cbind(letters[1:5], letters[6:10], letters[11:15])
df
 [,1] [,2] [,3] 
[1,] "a"  "f"  "k" 
[2,] "b"  "g"  "l" 
[3,] "c"  "h"  "m" 
[4,] "d"  "i"  "n" 
[5,] "e"  "j"  "o"
```

And what I would like is this:

```
newdf<-cbind(paste(df[,1],df[,2],sep=""),paste(df[,1],df[,3],sep=""),(paste(df[,2],df[,3],sep="")))
newdf
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "af" "ak" "fk"
[2,] "bg" "bl" "gl"
[3,] "ch" "cm" "hm"
[4,] "di" "dn" "in"
[5,] "ej" "eo" "jo"
```

The actual data may have hundreds of rows and/or columns, so obviously I need a less manual way of doing this. Any help is much appreciated, I am but a humble biologist and my skill set in this area is rather limited.

Comment: Do you want only pairs in the same order as your data frame? That is, why isn't "fa" or "ka" in your first row?

Comment: Thanks, the order isn't important in terms of identity, ie, "fa" ="af", but yes, the pairs should be in the same order as the data frame, as in the example

Answer (score 12):

A combination of `combn()` and `apply()` will get you all of the unordered pairwise combos:

```
df <- cbind(letters[1:5], letters[6:10], letters[11:15])

apply(X = combn(seq_len(ncol(df)), 2), 
      MAR = 2, 
      FUN = function(jj) {
          apply(df[, jj], 1, paste, collapse="")
      }      
)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "af" "ak" "fk"
# [2,] "bg" "bl" "gl"
# [3,] "ch" "cm" "hm"
# [4,] "di" "dn" "in"
# [5,] "ej" "eo" "jo"
```

(If what's going on in the above isn't immediately clear, you might want to have a quick look at the object returned by `combn(seq_len(ncol(df)), 2)`. Its columns enumerate all unordered pairwise combos integers between 1 and `n`, where `n` is the number of columns in your data frame.)

Comment: Thank you so much---this is exactly what I needed. Why didn't I post this question five hours ago? You all are great.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `FUN` argument to `combn` to paste together the columns from each combination:

```
combn(ncol(df),2,FUN=function(i) apply(df[,i],1,paste0,collapse=""))
```

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: what is obfuscated about it?  The `FUN` arg to `combn` may seem a bit odd, but it's really handy if there are a lot of combinations because you don't have to store all of them in an intermediate object.

Comment: @otherJosh -- Obfuscated was probably the wrong word. 'Compact' would have been better. As a formerly 'humble biologist' myself, I was just being mindful of how hard to parse this (and my answer for that matter) might be to the OP. (Just to be clear, I'm still a biologist --- just no longer a humble one ... ;)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: Good to know. I don't think of _obfuscated_ as a good thing. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Josh and Joshua's answers are better but I thought I'd give my approach:

This requires downloading [`qdap` varsion 1.1.0](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/qdap-1-1-0-released-on-cran/) using the `paste2` function:

```
library(qdap)

ind <- unique(t(apply(expand.grid(1:3, 1:3), 1, sort)))
ind <- ind[ind[, 1] != ind[, 2], ]
sapply(1:nrow(ind), function(i) paste2(df[, unlist(ind[i, ])], sep=""))
```

Though to steal from their answers this would be much more readable:

```
ind <- t(combn(seq_len(ncol(df)), 2))
sapply(1:nrow(ind), function(i) paste2(df[, unlist(ind[i, ])], sep=""))
```

Answer (score -1):

Remember that you will get a *lot* of columns in your new data.frame, given that you say you have hundreds of columns in the original data.frame: if the original data contain *n* columns, then the new one will contain *n(n-1)/2* columns - this scales quadratically.

Comment: This is not an answer; you should add this as a comment to the question.

Comment: I just tried to change this to a comment. However, with what little rep I have, it seems like I cannot yet comment on questions. Would it make sense for someone else to turn this into a comment, or would this cross the line to spam?